# Clipping Feature by using irregular polygon in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I want to clip the features based on selected polygon.I have the two layers "suburban" and "lot". I want to clip features of lot layer based on selected polygon from suburban layer.
I have tried manually in arc map 10.3 using Analaysis tools->Extract->Clip. It clipped lot features only which are underlying on selected polygons of suburban layer. But it's not working correctly when trying the same from ArcObjects .Net using geoprocessor interface.

[image: selected polygon on suburb layer]

It's not clipping the lot feature based on selected polygon of suburban layer.Instead of clipping the lot features based on all the polygon of the suburban layer.

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

I am also tried ITopologicalOperator QueryClipped functionality.It clip the features only in rectangular (envelop) size.It's not exactly clip the features based on irregular polygon boundary.

I am using the following code.

```vb
Private Sub lotClip(ByVal pInFClass As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass, ByVal clipGeometry As IGeometry, ByVal pClipFClass As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass, ByVal outputName As String)
        Dim clipperGeo As New ESRI.ArcGIS.AnalysisTools.Clip
        Dim Result As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessorResult2
        Try
            Using releaser As New ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ComReleaser
                releaser.ManageLifetime(clipperGeo)
                clipperGeo.in_features = pInFClass
                clipperGeo.clip_features = clipGeometry
                clipperGeo.out_feature_class = outputName
                Result = runClipTool(clipperGeo, Nothing)
                If Result Is Nothing Then
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Could not clip dataset")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                ReturnObjectfromResult(Result, "Feature Class")
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Clip error")
        End Try
    End Sub
    Friend Function runClipTool(ByVal Process As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.IGPProcess, ByVal TC As ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.ITrackCancel2) As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessorResult2
        Dim Result As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessorResult2
        Dim GP As New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor
        Try
            Result = CType(GP.Execute(Process, Nothing), ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessorResult2)
            If Result.Status <> ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.esriJobStatus.esriJobSucceeded Then returnMessages(Result, "Geoprocessing Error")
            GP.ClearMessages()
        Catch ex As Exception
            returnMessages(Result, "Fail")
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Run Geoprocessor")
        End Try
        Return Result
    End Function
    Friend Sub ReturnObjectfromResult(ByVal result As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessorResult2, ByVal Type As String)
        Dim GPVal As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IGPValue
        Dim InMemFC As String
        Dim GPUtil As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGPUtilities3 = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.GPUtilities
        Dim pOutputFc As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass
        Try
            GPVal = result.GetOutput(0)
            InMemFC = GPVal.GetAsText()

            Select Case Type
                Case "Feature Class"
                    pOutputFc = GPUtil.OpenFeatureClassFromString(InMemFC)
                Case "Table"
                    GPUtil.OpenTableFromString(InMemFC)
            End Select
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Return FeatureClass error")
        End Try

    End Sub
```

How do I clip the features based on an irregular polygon?

Comment: Pass in a FeatureLayer, these support Selections, not a FeatureClass.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already calling GP tools within your code, the easiest way to accomplish what your asking is to pass the result of the [Select Layer By Attribute GP tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) (or other selection tool) to the Clip GP tool. You will need to [convert the "suburban" feature class to a feature layer first](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm). The simple steps would be:

1. Convert suburban feature class to feature layer
2. Make selection on the suburban feature layer
3. Pass the result of the selection to the Clip tool as the clipping geometry

Answer (score 2):

The Clip tool should work, but I too have seen it not work correctly, even with the use of FeatureLayers. If Clip isn't behaving, my process is the following:

- Get the clipping geometry and cast as ITopologicalOperator
- Loop through the features will be clipped
- Use ITopological.Intersect to get the clipped geometry (Use intersect)
- If the returned geometry is empty/null, then your feature completely outside the clipping boundary.

Comment: Get the selected clip feature from pClipFClass with the IFeatureSelection interface, cursor and Union the clipping geometries with ITopologicalOperator for the final clip geometry and put it into an ISpatialFilter to select the lots from pInFClass with Search then this all works good... doing it this way means not processing geometries that have no spatial relationship with the clip which should be quicker provided the clip geometry doesn't cover almost all features to be clipped, but there's no way to tell that before running the Search.